# Limit decimal digits in Double Precision or float8 type in postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, floating-point, precision

I have a postgresql database and am using it for a project which handles monetary value. My question is:
How do I limit the number of decimal digits to two for a Double Precision or float8 type column in a postgresql table?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Simply use `Decimal` (`Numeric`) type instead, as [documented in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html), e.g. `cost decimal(10,2)`.

The first number (10) defines the total *length* of the number (all digits, including those after the decimal point), while the second number (2) tells how many of them are after the decimal point. The above declaration gives you 8 digits in front of the point. Of course, you can increase that - the limitations of the `Numeric` type are much, much higher.

In my opinion there is no need to use floating point when you handle currencies or other monetary-related values. I have no idea about the performance comparison between the two types, but `Decimal` has one advantage - it is an exact number (which usually is not the case with floating point). I also suggest to read an [interesting, but short discussion on the topic](http://forums.devshed.com/postgresql-help-21/numeric-vs-float-607281.html).

Comment: I agree. The `float` (or `real`) datatype isn't useful at all.

Comment: Ok. Another question, How do I declare a decimal data type in service.xml file in liferay mvc? Any Idea ?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no direct solution. A workaround, using Java's `BigDecimal`, [can be found in the comments to Liferay LEP-841](http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LEP-841). It is also [discussed in the forum](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/11788130). Hopefully you can find a solution; if not - post another question, I am sure someone have already done something similar.